# Can't find javax.faces.LogStrings bundle

Tags: java, maven, jsf

I use JSF 2.2 and i get this error when i run tomcat server.

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find javax.faces.LogStrings bundle
at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1945)
at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:380)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandLogger(LogManager.java:554)
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:455)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:553)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.<clinit>(FacesServlet.java:274)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:121)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

in the faces-config.xml i use :

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <supported-locale>fr</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

the messages.properties is palaced in resources folder

[image]

I don't know the sources of this Bug

the pom.xml look like:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- PROJECT LOMBOK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PRIMEFACES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAVA EE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Last I checked, Tomcat did not provide JSF implementation JAR. Did you add them manually?

Comment: Yes i add them manually

Comment: Uh, Tomcat is not a Java EE container and yet you're pretending it to be one.

Comment: Technically, this answers your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32734667

Comment: @BalusC Thank you very much, your proposition work :)